# Hibernate query by example (from Spring 3)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring

I've made my entity classes `Adress`, `Road` and `County`. A `Road` is in a `County` and an `Adress` in on a `Road`. I would like to list all the `Adresses` in a `County`. Therefore, in my `AdressService` I say:

```
public List<Adress> AllAdresses(County county) {
  Adress adress = new Adress();
  Road road = new Road();
  road.setCounty(county);
  adress.setRoad(road);

  Example example = Example.create(adress);
  return (List<Adress>) adressDAO.query(Adress.class, example);
}
```

In my `AdressDAO` I have query():

```
public List query(Class<?> c, Example example) {
  return getSession().createCriteria(c).add(example).setMaxResults(100).list();
}
```

This executes the following query on my database server:

```
select this_.AdressId as AdressId2_0_, 
       this_.Description as Descript3_2_0_, 
       this_.DescriptionShort as Descript4_2_0_, 
       this_.HouseLetter as HouseLetter2_0_, 
       this_.HouseNr as HouseNr2_0_, 
       this_.RoadId as RoadId2_0_ 
from tblAdress this_ 
where (this_.HouseNr=0) 
limit 100
```

I had expected it to at least include SOME information about my entity `County`, and an inner join with `tblRoad`. `tblRoad` has a primary key `roadId`, so I expected `this_.roadId` to be joined with `tblRoad.roadId`, and I expected `tblRoad.countyId` to be set to the primary key of `County`, that is `countyId`.

Why is the query in this example not built correctly when I use my own entity types? If I only use integers and strings, they work fine, but not entities. How do I make joins like this work with my own entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#querycriteria-examples):

> Version properties, identifiers and
>   associations are ignored

And that, as they say, is that.

Comment: I seemed to have read that somewhere, but I didn't quite believe that. Isn't there something I can do about it? Specifying something about depth or what association path to go or something?

Comment: Query-By-Example is a bit of a toy. If you need programmatic query construction, you should really be using the full Criteria API (which is what QBE uses under the covers, in a very limited way).

Comment: Aha, thank you very much for the tip. I'll dig back into the Hibernate Reference Documentation and learn about that. I thought that query by example was the way to go, it looks so generic and good. :-)

Comment: Super, I took your advice and the correct query now seems to be:
return adressDAO.getSession().createCriteria(Adress.class).createCriteria("road").add(Restrictions.eq("county", county)).setMaxResults(100).list();